# if $m>n$ prove that $ a^{2^n} + 1$ is a divisor of $a^{2^m} - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Stuck on this question without much progress. Problem no 49. Section 1.2 Niven. Any hints in the right direction ?
For the second part : How can I use this to find $gcd(a^{2^m}+1,a^{2^n}+1)$ ?

Comment: Question is a bit ambiguous. Did you mean $a^{2^n}+1$ is a divisor of $a^{2^m}-1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I am new here .

Comment: tried induction??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $a^{2^m}-1$ is a difference of two squares; factor it, and notice that one of the factors has the same form. (Properly speaking this should be turned into a proof by induction on $m\ge n+1$, but this is probably the easiest way to see what's going on.)

**Added:** For the second part, note that $a^{2^n}+1\mid a^{2^m}-1$, so the desired gcd must divide both $a^{2^m}-1$ and $a^{2^m}+1$.

Comment: Thanks Got the first part. Any hints for the second part?

Comment: @user1791066: You're welcome. See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=n+r$ where integer $r>0$

$$a^{2^m}-1=a^{2^{n+r}}-1=(a^{2^{n+1}})^{2^{r-1}}-1$$ which is divisible by $a^{2^{n+1}}-1=\left(a^{2^n}\right)^2-1=(a^{2^n}-1)(a^{2^n}+1)$ for $2^{r-1}\ge1\implies r\ge1$

Answer (score 1):

Using that for any natural $\;t\;$ we have that $\;x^t-1=(x-1)(x^{t-1}+x^{t-2}+\ldots+x+1)\;$ , we have the general claim:

$\;(x^m-1)\mid (x^n-1)\iff m\mid n\;$, because:

If $\;m\mid n\;$: then $\;n=km\;$ , and then

$$x^n-1=\left(x^m\right)^k-1=(x^m-1)\left((x^m)^{k-1}+(x^m)^{k-2}+\ldots+x^m+1\right)$$

If $\;(x^m-1)\mid (x^n-1)\;$: we get

$$x^n-1=(x^m-1)g(x)\;\;\;(**)$$

Let now $\;\xi\;$ be a [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) of order $\;m\;$ , and let us write (euclidean division algorithm)

$$n=mq+r\;,\;\;0\le|r|<m$$

By (**) above we have that

$$\;\xi^n-1=(\xi^m-1)g(\xi)=0\implies1=\xi^n=(\xi^m)^q\xi^r=\xi^r\;$$

and since $\;xi\;$ is primitive of order $\;n\;$ , we must have $\;r=0\;\implies n=mq\implies m\mid n\;$

Your question's answer follows now at once since

$$m>n\iff 2^n\mid 2^m\iff \left(x^{2^n}-1\right)\mid\left(x^{2^m}-1\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
First technique would be to use the following expression. This is only applicable when n is even.
$x^n-y^n = (x+y)(x^{n-1} - x^{n-2}y + x^{n-3}y^2 -x^{n-4}y^3 +  \dots +y^{n-1})$
Let $m = n + k.$
We can write $a^{2^m}-1$ as $(a^{2^n})^{2k}-1^{2k}$ and since m is even we can use above property.
We get
$$(a^{2^n})^{2k}-1^{2k} = (a^{2^n}+1)((a^{2^n})^{2k-1}-(a^{2^n})^{2k-2}+(a^{2^n})^{2k-3} -  \dots -1).$$
Let p = $(a^{2^n}+1)((a^{2^n})^{2k-1}-(a^{2^n})^{2k-2}+(a^{2^n})^{2k-3} -  \dots -1).$
We can see that $ \frac{(a^{2^m}-1)}{(a^{2^n}+1)}$ = $((a^{2^n})^{2k-1}-(a^{2^n})^{2k-2}+(a^{2^n})^{2k-3} - \dots -1)$

**Solution 2**
$a^{2^n}+1 \equiv 0\pmod {a^{2^n}+1}$
$a^{2^n} \equiv -1\pmod {a^{2^n}+1}$
$(a^{2^n})^{2^k} \equiv (-1)^{2^k}\pmod {a^{2^n}+1}$
$a^{2^m} \equiv 1 \pmod {a^{2^n}+1}$ .....m=n+k
$a^{2^m}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod {a^{2^n}+1}$ 
Therefore $a^{2^n}+1$ divides $a^{2^m}-1$.